# Microsoft.Project.Server.Library Sharepoint vdproj Dependency with Jenkins CI Server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, jenkins, dependencies, project-server

I have an MSI vdproj that inherits a reference to Microsoft.Project.Server.Library.  This project builds fine on a workstation, but when attempting to build from a CI server, it fails based on some Sharepoint dependencies (Microsoft.Sharepoint.Security.dll, etc).  How can we get around this without installing and licensing sharepoint (which we don't use nor need) on the Jenkins server?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the required DLLs from a SharePoint server to the CI server or to a network location accessible from the CI server.

Open the solution in Visual Studio on the CI server and add references to the required DLLs, browsing to their file paths. The solution should then build without complaint.

Comment: Thanks Thriggle, I will give it a try.